# Unable to send AT commands to c-06h

Tags: arduino

I'm unable to send AT commands from the Arduino serial monitor Tera Term.  s. The hc-06 led is flashing and not steady. However the  Android connects to the HC-06 , as indicated by steady led and the ability to control leds and motors. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The arduino can be connected to the android but unless you are sending data using the correct com port then no data will be transferred. Depending on what device you are using, usually you would go to the Bluetooth settings, select advanced settings or more settings(your device could say something different but it's the same concept) , then select the hc-06 and choose com ports. It will tell you the outgoing and incoming com ports. If you want to send information to motors like you said then you'd chose outgoing. You then simply enter that com port number into the terminal you are using and unless there are any problems in your code it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which bluetooth model you are using. But, when I worked with a blue tooth shield, I had a jumper in the shield, that will disconnect or connect the txt send and receive connections, and thats why I couldn't send programs or read data from the blue tooth device. 
Good luck